# Prevent this page from creating additional dialog causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript

So I made this math game, it creates 5 random math questions. The problem I'm having is with the prevent dialog checkbox. I could make this without using prompt/confirm but after testing them out I noticed that when the dialog box is checked it creates an infinite loop because of maximum call stacks. I know the prevent default box is hardcoded and nothing can be done to remove it with JS but what can I do to prevent this in my logic? I apologize if my code is hard to read.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/VodkaTonic/eB53d/3/

Here's a code example:

I have a Calculator class with methods I added to the prototype. Here is the constructor function and the first prototype method that returns an error.

```
function Calculator(num, num2) {
    this.num = num;
    this.num2 = num2;
}

Calculator.prototype = {
        constructor: Calculator,
    add: function () {
        var answer = this.num + this.num2,
            question = prompt("What's " + this.num + " + " + this.num2 + " = ?");
        console.log(answer === parseInt(question, 10));
        return (parseInt(question, 10) === answer) ? correct.call(this) : incorrect.call(this, 'add', question);
    }
```

Depending on if the answer is correct or not, it calls either the correct or incorrect function. Here's an example of the incorrect function:

```
function incorrect(calc, answer) {
    if (!answer) {
        var conf = confirm("You didn't select an answer! Press Ok to exit the game or Cancel to continue!");
        if (!conf) {
            return this[calc]();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    alert(answer + " is incorrect!");
    return this[calc]();
}
```

When the prevent dialog box is checked, false is returned thousands of times.

This is the error it returns.

```
<error> VM150:160
InjectedScript.wrapObject VM150:160
Calculator.add (index):77
incorrect (index):56
Calculator.add (index):78
incorrect
```

Comment: Please produce a reduced code sample demonstrating the problem, and include it in the question itself.

Comment: Just a side note: I would not use alert windows for this purpose. The problem with alerts is that the way the are displayed is very browser/platform-dependent. If you want to make any customizations at all, use some other approach like Bootstrap modals. And by the way: it is intentional that scripts cannot disable prevent dialog checkbox. The whole point with that checkbox is that users can disable popup generation in annoying websites. I'd definitely not want to have that checkbox disabled for any websites.

Comment: I completely agree, you shouldn't be able to remove it. I'm just trying to figure out why my code goes into an infinite loop when it is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of the infinite loop is caused by your calling sequence. Psuedo of your code

```
Pose question:
poses a question in a alert box
if correct->couter++ & call 'pose question'      <== this is the problem
if incorrect->call 'pose question'               <== this is the problem
```

Although you're using 'return someMethod()', the "someMethod" will call correct/incorrect again in a sychronous way. Hence, just building up as stack each time this loop occurs (each question posed).